How to make a NextJS server sub-component dynamically re-render
NextJS v14.2
React v18.3
I have a NavBar (navbar.tsx below) component  which is present on all pages via layout.tsx
I have a ShadUI dropdown menu (dropdown.tsx below) which is a subcomponent of navbar
Both components are server side.
navbar.tsx
import Link from 'next/link'

import './navbar.css'

import DropDown from './dropdown'
import GetUser from '@/app/components/getUser'

/*
NAVBAR

links to history, draw and members list pages

gets user from layout.tsx and forwards data to dropdown component

*/

type typeNavProps = {
    name: string,
    loggedEmail: string,
    isLoggedOn: boolean,
    isAdmin: boolean
}

export default async function Navbar() {
    const navBarProps: typeNavProps = await GetUser()

    console.log('Fired NavBar with user: ', navBarProps.name)

    return (
        <nav className="navbar">
            <div className="navbar__container">
                <Link href="/login" id="navbar__logo">The Slade</Link>
                <div className="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                    <span className="bar"></span> <span className="bar"></span>
                    <span className="bar"></span>
                </div>
                <ul className="navbar__menu">
                    <li className="navbar__item">
                        <Link href="/history" className="navbar__links">History</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="navbar__item">
                        <Link href="/draw" className="navbar__links">Draw</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="navbar__item">
                        <Link href="/members" className="navbar__links">Members List</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <DropDown
                            name={navBarProps.name}
                            loggedEmail={navBarProps.loggedEmail}
                            isLoggedOn={navBarProps.isLoggedOn}
                            isAdmin={navBarProps.isAdmin}
                        />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}


dropdown.tsx
import Link from 'next/link'

import {
    DropdownMenu,
    DropdownMenuContent,
    DropdownMenuItem,
    //DropdownMenuLabel,
    //DropdownMenuSeparator,
    DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu"

type typeNavProps = {
    name: string,
    loggedEmail: string,
    isLoggedOn: boolean,
    isAdmin: boolean
}

/* 
DROPDOWN BOX  is from shadui
gets user data from layout.tsx via navbar using navBarProps
    displays name of user
    and cuts available options if not an admin
*/

export default function DropDown(navBarProps: typeNavProps) {

    console.log('Fired dropdown with props from navbar: ', navBarProps)

    if (navBarProps.isAdmin) {
        return (
            <>
                <DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownMenuTrigger>{navBarProps.name}</DropdownMenuTrigger>
                    <DropdownMenuContent className='mt-10'>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/login" >Log In</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/logout" >Log Out</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/updatemail" >Update Email</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/updatepassword" >Update Password</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/updateadmin" >Update Admin</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/updateactive" >Update Active</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/emailinvite" >Send Email Invitation</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                    </DropdownMenuContent>
                </DropdownMenu>
            </>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                <DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownMenuTrigger>{navBarProps.name}</DropdownMenuTrigger>
                    <DropdownMenuContent className='mt-10'>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/login" >Log In</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/logout" >Log Out</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/updatemail" >Update Email</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                        <DropdownMenuItem>
                            <Link href="/updatepassword" >Update Password</Link>
                        </DropdownMenuItem>
                    </DropdownMenuContent>
                </DropdownMenu>
            </>
        )
    }
}


route.ts
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"

import { createClient } from '@/app/utils/supabase/server'
import { NextApiRequest } from "next"

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
    console.log('logoutUser was fired with: ', req)

    const supabase = createClient()

    const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut()
    if (error) {
        console.log('error logging out in logout route: ', error)
    }

    redirect('/')
}


If I log a user in then the setup works fine.  The user is lands on a login page and upon successful login, is redirected to the members page, the navbar/dropdown is refreshed to reflect the users role (admin or not admin).
However
When I log out (GET call to route.ts) the user is logged out and redirected to ‘/‘ as planned, the navbar is called (I can see this in console)…..  but….  The dropdown does not refresh with the new user data (e.g. 'No logged user' and isAdmin = false.
A reload of ‘/‘ solves the problem.
Adding revalidate('/') in route.ts does not solve the problem.
Adding 'headers' to the / page, in order to get the page to dynamically render  as per Vercel's Youtube video Next.js App Router Caching: Explained! does not solve the problem.
I think I am missing something fundamental, which is why I have not listed all the things I have tried. I would be grateful for some help.

revalidate('/')  or revalidatePath('/')?

Thank you...  I have already tried those

The NextJS's 'Link' REACT component relies on link prefetching.  This has a default cache of 30 seconds even for dynamic rendering.
This is explained here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/staleTimes
Making 'dynamic: 0' in my next.config.js file solved the issue for me
Please note that 'dynamic: 0' is the default behaviour in NextJS v15, see https://nextjs.org/blog/next-15-rc#caching-updates
